# Copy multiple files from one share folder to different folder share

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, file-copying

I have list of files which i need to copy to a different share folder with same folder structure.

Input:

```
\\myshare1\foldername1\foldername2\file1.txt
\\myshare1\foldername1\foldername2\file2.txt
\\myshare1\foldername3\foldername4\file1.txt
\\myshare1\foldername3\foldername1\file4.txt
```

Output : Copy all the files to \\myshare2 with the same folder structure. If the folder is there skip the folder creation and if not create the folder.

```
\\myshare2\foldername1\foldername2\file1.txt
\\myshare2\foldername1\foldername2\file2.txt
\\myshare2\foldername3\foldername4\file1.txt
\\myshare2\foldername3\foldername1\file4.txt
```

Comment: ok, what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Could you at least show the code you have so far, and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a foreach on your folder to get all the file names and send each file to the following method

```
public void CopyFiles(string sourcePath)
{
    string destination = "myshare2";
    string source = sourcePath.Replace("myshare1","");

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists($"{destination}{source}"))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($"{destination}{source}");
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, $"{destination}{source}", true);
    }     
}
```